# i having trouble with GOPATH and Intellij idea

Tags: rest, intellij-idea, go, path

I use MACOSX 10.10.5 and use Intellij IDEA as IDE.

I already install GO SDK (by download SDK from website and not from Macports)and try simple program, it work correctly.

I try to use gorilla library (http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#overview), So I set GOPATH like this

- GOPATH=$HOME/work
- PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
- go get github.com/gorilla/mux

and Add PATH to intellij, see figure below. [image: Set gorilla library]

When i import this library IDE throw error like this.[image]

So i try to fixit like this [I use IntelliJ IDEA as golang IDE, and system environment have already set GOPATH，But IDEA can't load it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771091/i-use-intellij-idea-as-golang-ide-and-system-environment-have-already-set-gopat)

But it do not work for me. how can I set GOPATH in idea?

Comment: Are you using the version out of the IntelliJ plugin repository or the nightly/alpha builds from [here](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin)? The latest builds should autodetect `$GOPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771091/i-use-intellij-idea-as-golang-ide-and-system-environment-have-already-set-gopat) you mentioned is about old version of plugin. For the new version GOPATH is defined in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Go | Go Libraries`. There you also can see whether GOPATH system environment variable was found or not and add your custom GOPATHs.

See also [documentation](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/wiki/Documentation#changing-the-go-libraries-gopath-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047) you can see the menu path:

Languages & Frameworks > Go > Go SDK

I'm using brew, so it's /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec currently.